# Still running old version of relay after apt-get upgrade

Tags: update

Noob question.

I got the message "Please upgrade! This version of Tor (#.#.#.#) is not recommended, according to the directory authorities. Recommended versions are..."

So I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` (I'll have to look into unattended upgrades someday) and my tor relay got upgraded to 0.2.9.14 but it seems 0.3.1.9 is already released. Why wasn't I upgraded to 0.3.1.9?

Is there just a delay before it gets to Debian repositories? It just seems really far behind.

I'm running Raspbian Stretch Lite on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Update, I can see from Debian's package search that I have the latest version for Debian Stretch.

Search is here:
https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=tor

I'm still feeling outdated though. I want my relay to be better than everyone else's! :P

Answer (score 2):

0.2.9.* is the current Long Term Support (LTS) series and is a perfectly fine series to be tracking.

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/teams/NetworkTeam/CoreTorReleases

The Tor Project's repositories will generally have versions in the newer stable series. Historically, Raspberry Pis had a CPU architecture that is incompatible with the "armhf" arch name that Debian uses, leading to issues. I **think** rpi3 doesn't have that issue anymore. Read the warnings on the page and proceed at your own risk: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

Comment: I'd quickly add that while 0.2.9.x series is still supported and will get security updates, 0.3.1.x does have some nice new features (like the netflow padding, etc) which could be advantageous in some cases (but only if your guard is also 0.3.1.x).